# Is it possible to enable going to the bottom of the context menu from top with pressing up key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu

I want to navigate between the last item and first one in context menu using arrow keys. Normally in linux it would go to bottom when I press the up arrow key when in first item. But in MacOS it stays in the first one. How can I activate that circular behavior?

I did some search but couldn't find anything.

[image: First item is highlighted]

[image: Then I need to navigate all the way down in order to select the last one]

Comment: Please consider putting your solution as an answer instead of editing your question. This will allow for others that come across this question to have another option they can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to jump from the top item on the context menu to the bottom item on the context menu, and from the bottom item on the context menu to the top item on the context menu, you need to use the **⌘** *key* in conjunction with the *down-arrow* and *up-arrow* respectively.

Press **⌘ Up-Arrow** to highlight the top item on the context menu, releasing the *keys*, then press  **⌘ Down-Arrow** to highlight the bottom item on the context menu.

[image]

Comment: In my quick testing, the alt key works as well.

Comment: Throughout all of macOS, cmd+arrow normally means "to beginning" or "to end" (of line, or document, etc.). Alt+arrow skips only a "section" (word or line) at a time, always smaller than cmd+arrow, so it's interesting they have the same behaviour here.

Comment: I was using cmd+arrow for another shortcut. It is good that alt+arrow also works. Thanks a lot! Altough it seems I'll need to change my shortcuts as I miss some default behaviors currently.

Answer (score 0):

Found a perfect solution. I realized that when you type a letter, selection directly jumps into the item that starts with that letter. You can type words and it goes to first match. That's really useful.

Sometimes I don't get why Apple lacks some features but then I realize I don't actually need them.

I won't change the selected answer as it exactly explains what I've asked. But I'm also sharing this as it helped me to solve the issue I was having.

Comment: Might be worth noting that using the first letter is language-sensitive while Cmd-Arrow isn't